# file_put_contents writing include to new file

Tags: php

I have a variable that contains an array from form data, seen below:

```
$option1 = explode("\n", $_POST['form1']);
```

I then write the array to another file:

```
$test = array($option1);
$file = 'test.php';
file_put_contents($file, '<?php \n\n $array=' . var_export($test, true) . ';' . '\n');
```

I would like to write/include a file or a large amount of code in the test.php file above to manipulate the $array. When trying the below code it just prints the contents of the include file to the current page instead of writing it:

```
file_put_contents($file, include('includefile.php'));
```

Comment: Can I ask what your end goal is?  It seems to me that something very, very wrong is happening here.

Comment: Agree with @Corbin - please share your use-case. You have the potential for a serious security hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well, you would like include the code from `includefile.php` into your test.php ?

You can't use include like that, but you should do it like that.

```
file_put_contents($file, file_get_contents('includefile.php'), FILE_APPEND);
```

This will append the content from `includefile.php` into your `test.php`

Comment: +1 for a working answer. Security concerns are very well noted in comments and other answers - hopefully the OP will respond to them!

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure of your purpose but generating code dynamically for execution is not a good idea in term of security. what hapens if there is exception while writting your array.
The script you would be trying to execute would be unknown .

I would recommmed you to think of outputing your array in string link Json or init 
inside the file. then reload it when you need along with your array manipulator "includefile.php" using json_decode or parse_ini...